# How to insert the data while closing the browser tab or browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to check my registers users active or not for that users came to my index.php page i want to insert the table through session user1 is active and same time without logout user1 is closing the browser tab or browser the table should be update user1 is inactive.

Advice me it's possible to do that, can do mean please help me how to do that part or is there any possible way to do that same function.

Comment: try with [onbeforeunload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is quite easy to implement this. You can make an AJAX call on `onbeforeunload()` and then handle that AJAX request and update the status of the user in the table. You can get the user from SESSION[] array.

Comment: i can get the user table data from session

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onbeforeunload` event handler in Javascript.

[More details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: this function is working while closing the tab and browser database table update also working but one issue is when refresh the page also that script trigger the sql how to stop that

Answer (score 0):

```
 var inFormOrLink;

            $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
                return inFormOrLink ? "Do you really want to close?" : null;
            })
```

this code is working but this message is not coming ('Changes you made may not be saved') this message only coming why is that?